# Add SQL Shell (psql) (postgres) to Windows Terminal

Tags: psql, windows-terminal

I'm trying to add a new terminal Postgres shell (psql) to the Windows Terminal. I want to add it to the profiles list in the settings.

This is the windows terminal.

[image: windows terminal]

In the settings file, we can add a list of profiles. In that list, I have Windows PowerShell, Command prompt, and Azure Cloud Shell.

How do I add psql shell on that list?

```
    {
          "guid": "{some guid}",
          "hidden": false,
          "name": "SQL Shell (psql)",
          "source": ?
    }
```

I looked up various articles on this, but none of them has a working solution.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you mean with "add to Windows Terminal"? Can't you just run `psql` from within a command line window (`cmd.exe`)?

Comment: I'll elaborate on my question.

Comment: What about `"source": "psql.exe"` (I have never used this, so I'm just guessing)

Comment: I tried, not working. I think we need to specify the whole path maybe.

Comment: You can generate a guid pretty easily, just search for it in google. Then you will need to give it a name and specify the path, more than likely it will be the WHOLE path. You may also just want to change the installation location of the psql shell or make a copy, throw that in the same place as cmd and powershell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[I somehow figured it out!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhN0s.jpg)
The profile settings are:

```
{
    "commandline" : "\"%PROGRAMFILES%\\PostgreSQL\\12\\scripts\\runpsql.bat\" -i -l",
    "hidden": false,
    "name": "PostgreSQL",
    "icon" : "PostgreSQL.png*",
    "background" : "#1b364d",
    "cursorShape" : "vintage"
}
```

I also searched for the guid for some time, and then I remembered that I had added Git Bash to Windows Terminal. So I copied that executable, replaced the value with psql batch file address, and voilà!

*[PostgreSQL.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTths.png)

Comment: Why not use `psql.exe` directly?

Comment: what was the reason for using `-i -l` in `"commandline" :` path ? I run it without them just: "commandline" : "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/14/scripts/runpsql.bat",

Answer (score 2):

you can get the guid down below if you want, i got it from here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/datatype-uuid.html

```
"guid": "{a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11}",
"name" : "SQL psql",
"commandline": "%PROGRAMFILES%/PostgreSQL/13/scripts/runpsql.bat -i -l",
"hidden": false,
"icon": "%SystemDrive%/PROGRA~1/PostgreSQL/13/scripts/images/pg-psql.ico",
```

Comment: Would anyone know why I'm getting prompted to set up a username and db when I launch the SQL shell this way? I'm afraid to enter anything because I already have  a dB and admin users.